# Why can't sympy integrate this (Mathematica can)

Tags: python, sympy, integral, calculus

Why can `sympy` not carry out this integral:

```
import sympy as sp
x = sp.symbols('x', real=True, nonzero=True)
sp.integrate(x**3/(sp.exp(x)-1), (x, 0, sp.oo))
```

this should return pi^4/15.

Comment: do you mean `x**(3/(sp.exp(x)-1))` or `(x**3) / (sp.exp(x)-1)` ? what doesn't work? error? wrong value? 42 ?

Comment: no, as written: `(x**3)/(sp.exp(1)-1)`. It does not return a result, just an object of type `sympy.integrals.risch.NonElementaryIntegral`. I want the symbolic result of pi4/15.

Comment: There are many integrals that SymPy cannot find and other software can. This is one of them. Open an [issue](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues) in the tracker.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Integral` and then evaluate the function using `evalf'

```
import sympy as sp
from sympy import Integral, oo, exp, pi, integrate
from sympy.abc import a, x, y
x = Integral(x**3/(exp(x)-1), (x, 0, oo))
x.evalf()
```

Comment: this is a numerical integration, I assume? Is there a way to get the symbolic result as well?

Comment: Not with sympy, I don't think any other python package will do that too

Comment: I'm asking because Mathematica can do it and was wondering if I was just doing it wrong in `sympy`.